# How do I list contents of a tar file without extracting it in python?

Tags: python, compression, gzip, extract

I've got a huge *.tar.gz file and I want to see the list of files contained in it without extracting the contents (preferably with mtimes per file). How can I achieve that in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting gzip folder of files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680023/extracting-gzip-folder-of-files-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TarFile.getnames() like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tarfile
tarf = tarfile.open('foo.tar.gz', 'r:gz')
print(tarf.getnames())
```

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames

And if you want mtime values you can use getmembers().

```
print([(member.name, member.mtime) for member in tarf.getmembers()])
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry it was my inattentiveness to not check tarfile description, since I did look at that doc page. :)

Comment: What if it's a straight gzip file without tar? e.g. xxx.gz