# How to check if a tar file is not empty before unpacking it with Python 3?

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

I wish to unpack some tar archives but I only want to rpcess non-empty ones. I found some code for `gzip` archives [How to check empty gzip file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874936/how-to-check-empty-gzip-file-in-python) and also this:

```
async def is_nonempty_tar_file(self, tarfile):
    with open(tarfile, "rb") as f:
        try:
            file_content = f.read(1)
            return len(file_content) > 1
        except Exception as exc:
            self.logger.error(
                f"Reading tarfile failed for {tarfile}", exc_info=True
            )
```

All the tar archives both empty and non-empty ones seem to have at least thsi character in them `\x1f`. SO they all pass the test even if they are empty.

How else can I check this?

Comment: How about using your command line utils, like `tar -tvf [tarfile]`, and checking if it contains anything?

Comment: Hey. I want to use python, I am writing a python service. So I am looking for a python tool to do what you suggest

Comment: Why don't you just try unpacking it?  Surely that's just as quick as checking first?

Comment: cause I want to make a list with the empty and a list with the non-empty ones also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a way using the `getmembers()` method from `tarfile` module. I made this method that checks for non empty tarfiles:

```
 def is_nonempty_tar_file(self, archive):
    with tarfile.open(archive, "r") as tar:
        try:
            file_content = tar.getmembers()
            return len(file_content) > 0
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Reading tarfile failed for {archive}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list contents of tarfiles with the `tarfile` module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#command-line-options

You probably can just use `tarfile.open` and check if the descriptor contains anything.

```py
import tarfile

x = tarfile.open("the_file.tar")
x.list()
```

Comment: I found a  way with getmembers() but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid listing all members (which can be costly on a large tarfile), you can also check if there is at least one member:

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("the_file.tar")

if tar.next() is None:
    print("The tarfile is empty")
else:
    print("The tarfile has at least one member")
```

At least in my tests, it seems that this does not impact a later call to `tar.extractall()`, so the `tar.next()` call does not seem to advance the position in a way that impacts that, as the name `next` might indicate.