# gzip.read32 method not available in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on a function with Python 3 which retrieves the name of a zipped file in a compressed folder.
 Fortunately I found a solution at the following link [How do I list contents of a gz file without extracting it in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592099/how-do-i-list-contents-of-a-gz-file-without-extracting-it-in-python)

The problem is that if I compile in Python 2.7.x everything works fine, while if I compile in Python 3.9.x it falls into error on the method `gzip.read32`. 
Error:

> AttributeError: module 'gzip' has no attribute 'read32'

Could this method have been omitted or renamed in Python 3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the exact issue that led to `read32` being removed, according to the relevant commits in the source code: https://bugs.python.org/issue1159051. Might be a good starting point.

Comment: @user3840170 Because that returns the container file's name, not the original file name which the compressed data had.

Comment: I added a new answer on the question you link to. Thus I think it would now make sense to close this as a duplicate (but I'm out of close votes for today).