# Python seedir treat zip/gzip files as directories?

Tags: python

I am using the [seedir library](https://github.com/earnestt1234/seedir) to handle folder/file STDOUT and it works quite nicely.  I wonder if there is an option to treat zip/gzip files as folder and list the individual files contained?

If this is not built in, would the proper solution be to [extend seedir](https://earnestt1234.github.io/seedir/seedir/index.html#extending-seedir)?

thx

Answer (score 0):

seedir creator here!  Thanks for sharing this question, I had never thought to do this.  I think you are right that creating your own version of `seedir.folderstructure.FolderStructure` is the best way to proceed.  Not sure if you are still interested in this, but here is what I came up with:

```py
import os
import zipfile

from seedir.folderstructure import FolderStructure

def getname_func(item):
    if isinstance(item, zipfile.Path):
        return item.filename.name
    else:
        return os.path.basename(item)

def isdir_func(item):
    if isinstance(item, zipfile.Path):
        return item.is_dir()
    elif zipfile.is_zipfile(item):
        return True
    else:
        return os.path.isdir(item)

def listdir_func(item):
    if isinstance(item, zipfile.Path):
        return list(item.iterdir())
    elif zipfile.is_zipfile(item):
        return list(zipfile.Path(item).iterdir())
    else:
        return [os.path.join(item, x) for x in os.listdir(item)]

# initialize
ZipFolderStructure = FolderStructure(getname_func, isdir_func, listdir_func)

# run on your folder
ZipFolderStructure('/Users/earnestt1234/Desktop/test')
```

Basically, we are creating a traversal system which is prepared to see either string paths (like default seedir) or [`zipfile.Path` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#path-objects).  The latter allows us to look through the zip contents.

To do this, we need to handle some potential cases in functions used to initialize `FolderStructure`:

For `getname_func`, which dictates how items are represented in the diagram:

- if we see a string path, return its basename
- a `zipfile.Path`, use `item.filename.name` to get its name

For `isdir_func`, which determines what items are traversed:

- if we see a `zipfile.Path`, use the `is_dir()` function
- if we see a string path that is also a zip, return `True` (we want to traverse these)
- for other string paths, just check if it is a folder

For `listdir_func`, which determines the children of any item we try to traverse:

- if we see a `zipfile.Path`, use the `iterdir()` method
- if we see a string path that is a zip file, first convert to a `zipfile.Path` and then use `iterdir()`
- for other string paths, return the absolute path of each child

---

Here's a demonstration.  I created a directory with `sd.randomdir(seed=4).realize()`.  I then created a zip of it in the same folder.  If I call the basic seedir, the zip is not expanded:

```
>>> import seedir as sd
>>> sd.seedir('test')
test/
├─MyFakeDir/
│ ├─Burt/
│ │ ├─phase/
│ │ ├─waffle.txt
│ │ ├─phagocyte.txt
│ │ ├─ersatz/
│ │ │ └─Byrd.txt
│ │ ├─blend/
│ │ └─exec.txt
│ └─emetic.txt
└─MyFakeDir.zip
```

But if I use the `ZipFolderStructure`, I can see the contents:

```
>>> ZipFolderStructure('test')
test/
├─MyFakeDir/
│ ├─Burt/
│ │ ├─phase/
│ │ ├─waffle.txt
│ │ ├─phagocyte.txt
│ │ ├─ersatz/
│ │ │ └─Byrd.txt
│ │ ├─blend/
│ │ └─exec.txt
│ └─emetic.txt
└─MyFakeDir.zip/
  └─MyFakeDir/
    ├─Burt/
    │ ├─phase/
    │ ├─waffle.txt
    │ ├─phagocyte.txt
    │ ├─ersatz/
    │ │ └─Byrd.txt
    │ ├─blend/
    │ └─exec.txt
    └─emetic.txt
```

---

Note that this is only going to handle zip files.  Since zipfile provides the object-oriented interface with zips, we can do this.  The same is not available for gzips, and either way [it looks like doing so is in principle impossible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592219/13386979)

Comment: Yep we ended up with very similar solutions, thanks for weighing in and creating seedir!